# MS-Word Office.js equivalent for `Selection.MoveRight` function in VBA

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

I'm converting from VBA to Office.js and I'm unable to find an office.js function for Word that is equivalent to `Selection.MoveRight` function in VBA. Is there a simple way to do similar things?

For example, I have a string of characters and inline images, and I would like to move right for designated N characters (including inline images), then insert a line break:

[image: Example]

This is easy to do in VBA like below. How could I do the same thing in office.js?

```
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:= N
Selection.TypeParagraph
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent for MoveRight in the Office JavaScript library. Something you might try to get the results you want:

Use the Range.getOOXML() method to get the underlying OOXML of the range. Add OOXML line breaks. Then use Range.insertOOXML() to replace the original range with the new one.